# how to split wordpress meta value

Tags: wordpress

// how to get "bigimg_link" and "section_content" in this value

```
 [section2_grey_section] => Array
    (
        [0] => a:3:{i:0;a:3:  {s:14:"bigimg_link_id";i:21;s:11:"bigimg_link";s:76:"http://www.w.xxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/celebrate_icon1.png";s:15:"section_content";s:152:"<h4>Need a <span>Green Lawn for Mehendi</span> ceremony?</h4>
        <p>Use our Grasslands, Palm Grove, Mango Grove, Green Sparkle just the way you want! </p>";}i:1;a:3:{s:14:"bigimg_link_id";i:22;s:11:"bigimg_link";s:76:"http://www.w.xxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/celebrate_icon2.png";s:15:"section_content";s:156:"<h4>Need a cozy 
          <span>banquet room</span> for haldi?</h4>
        <p>Our 2360 sq.ft./ 4000 sq.ft. Banquet rooms stand ready for you and your close knit family.</p>"; }i:2;a:3:{s:14:"bigimg_link_id";i:23;s:11:"bigimg_link";s:76:"http://www.w.xxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/celebrate_icon3.png";s:15:"section_content";s:146:"<h4>Got  <span>Cocktail, Bachelors or Hens</span> in mind?</h4>
        <p>Our hill surrounded outdoor spaces are idyllic for letting yourself loose.</p>";}}
    )
```

Anyone plese help me..Thanks in advance

Comment: Also post what you have tried, which shows some of your hardwork

Answer (score 2):

if your want to access this data, then you need to unserialize the array..

```
$data['section2_grey_section'];
$result = unserialize($data['section2_grey_section']['0']);
```

With unserialize the data converts in array form..
Then you can use fields..

```
$result['bigimg_link']
```